# How is the trajectory of a gravitational assist flyby mission computed?

Tags: mission-design, gravity-assist

Based on much research after posing my [previous question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/65100/12102), as well as the discussions with the rest of the community, I now (think I have) a deeper understanding of how mission planning works.

Based on what I have read, the feasibility of certain trajectories can be determined by comparing porkchop plots of the trajectories. For example, for a mission to Mars, the porkchop plots of a direct transfer to Mars vs a gravitational assist from Venus, then to Mars can be compared. See this answer:
[Brendan Luke's Answer on the Feasibility of Earth-Venus-Mars Missions](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/59558/would-it-be-practical-to-fly-a-probe-to-mars-using-gravitational-assistance-from/59585#59585)

My question therefore is this: Given a specific delta-v and launch date from Porkchop or other similar plots, how can I know the specific trajectory this corresponds to? I have some understanding of B-Plane targeting if it helps.